# Check if music has ended, OnStopped?

Tags: c++, events, sfml

Is it possible to make SFML 1.6 handle end of music by itself? Currently I have this:

```
//in music.cpp
music.Play()

//in main.cpp
//on every frame check for end of music
if(music.getStatus() == Sound::Stopped)
    loadNextMusicFile();
```

Isn't there a way in SFML to just say, "Play until music stopped, then load the next," without implementing this yourself? Or at least a more "elegant" way of noticing when the music stopped (like an OnStopped event)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code from Music.cpp

```
bool Music::OnGetData(SoundStream::Chunk& data)
{
    Lock lock(myMutex);

    // Fill the chunk parameters
    data.Samples   = &mySamples[0];
    data.NbSamples = myFile->Read(&mySamples[0], mySamples.size());

    // Check if we have reached the end of the audio file
    return data.NbSamples == mySamples.size();
}
```

You see that it will return false when its at the end of the file.

So what you want to do is subclass sf::Music. e.g.

```
class MyMusic : public sf::Music
{
   bool OnGetData(SoundStream::Chunk& data)
   {
       bool running = sf::Music::OnGetData(data);
       if(!running)
          OnMusicEnd();
       return running;
   }
public:
   void OnMusicEnd()
   {
       // ...
   }

};
```

Comment: No its not, its protected in sf::Music... why wouldn't it work?

Comment: "virtual bool OnGetData(Chunk& Data)" is under "private:" in Music.hpp, SFML 1.6

Comment: I see, its protected in SFML 2.0, maybe you should mention which version you are using in your question.

Comment: Added the 1.6 info. Sorry for forgetting it. So is there a possibility to modify your code to make it working with 1.6?

Comment: In that case I suggest that you create your own Music class where it is protected. Just look at the code in Music.cpp and use it in your own class. Its not much code.